# serialize/deserialize enum as element name (rather than element content/value)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I need to deserialize/serialize XML which looks like this:

```
<color>
    <green/>
</color>
```

where `<green/>` may be `<red/>`, `<blue/>` etc. - very large (but limited) set.

I'd like to describe it as simple enum in my code:

```
enum ColorName
{
    [XmlEnum("red")]
    Red,
    [XmlEnum("green")]
    Green,
    [XmlEnum("blue")]
    Blue,

    ...
    etc.
}
```

But, if I write my object model like this:

```
class Color
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public ColorName ColorName;
}

class Something
{
    [XmlElement("color")]
    public Color Color;
}
```

enum gets into XML as a value, rather than element name:

```
<color>
    <name>green</name>
</color>
```

**Is there any way to get enum value written into XML element name (see the first XML snippet - that's the goal), rather than XML element value**, without having to re-type all the values (it's a very large set) as empty class names, or resorting to custom serialization (I would like to avoid it, because serialized class contains a lot of other members, which are perfectly serialized by default)?

(I can't change the schema, it's third-party).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported by simply decorading your classes with `[Xml*]` attributes. You will have to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `Something` and do it yourself. Note that in most cases you don't have to bother with the `GetSchema` method; implementing `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` is just fine.